# removeClass not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to target the next set of html elements that I want to run `removeClass` on. I have tried many different versions of `.next() .find() eq() :last` but can't seem to make it remove the class.

I have made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StudentRik/69vsmddr/) with the code I am using.

I want to remove the 2nd set of `.tm-title h3` but looking in the source of the page it is always there the first `tm-title h3:first` is removed but the next set doesn't seem to work no matter what combination of selectors I have tried.

Comment: What do you mean "looking in the source of the page"? If you use the browser's "View Page Source" option it would show the original source as originally returned by the web server, not html corresponding to the current state of the page after it was modified by JS.

Comment: Just add jQuery and correct var name's: _https://jsfiddle.net/69vsmddr/5/_

Comment: Code relevant to the question goes ***in*** the question, not just linked.

Comment: @TusharGupta If you are answering it would be best to place the answer in the answer section with your relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem in the selector

```
var currentMonth = $('.curMonth').text();
var currentSplit = currentMonth.split(" ");
var curMonth = currentSplit[0].toLowerCase();

// find current month and hide div
$('.' + curMonth).removeClass('eventCal')
    .find('.tm-title h3:first')
    .removeClass('curMonth')
//now it is referring to the h3 element so .next() won't work as the second title is a sibling of first h3
    .end()
    .find('.tm-title h3')
    .removeClass('nextMonth');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g50ewsgb/)